# Calculating a Fisher expected information

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1,..., X_n$ be a random sample from a distribution with probability density function $f(x;\theta) = (1/2\theta) exp(-|x|/\theta)$ for $-\infty<x<\infty$.

(a) Find the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$ and calculate the Fisher (expected) information in the sample.

I've calculated the MLE to be $\sum |X_i|/n$ and I know the definition of Fisher expectation, but I'm getting really stuck with calculating it. I think the $|X_i|$ terms are throwing me off.

Any help in doing this problem would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that $$I(\theta)=-\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2}l(X\,| \,\theta)\right]\,$$
under certain regularity conditions (that apply here), where $I$ is the Fisher information and $l$ is the log-likelihood function of $X$. The log-likelihood function in this case is given by $$\begin{align} l(X\,|\,\theta) &=\text{log}f(X\,|\,\theta) \\&=\log\left(\frac{1}{2\theta}\text{exp}\left(-\frac{|X|}{\theta}\right)\right) \\ &= -\frac{|X|}{\theta} - \text{log}(2\theta)\,\,. \end{align}$$
It follows that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}l(X \,|\,\theta) = \frac{|X|}{\theta^2}-\frac{1}{\theta} \implies \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2}l(X \,|\,\theta) = -\frac{2|X|}{\theta^3}+\frac{1}{\theta^2}\,.$$
So, we have
$$I(\theta)=-\mathbb{E}\left[-\frac{2|X|}{\theta^3}+\frac{1}{\theta^2}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{2|X|}{\theta^3}-\frac{1}{\theta^2}\right]=\frac{2}{\theta^3}\mathbb{E}(\,|X|\,)-\frac{1}{\theta^2}\,.$$
It remains to compute the expectation of $|X|$. To this end, I will set up the integral. By definition of expected value for transformations of continuous random variables, we have
$$\mathbb{E}(\,|X|\,)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x|\,f(x \,|\, \theta)\,\text{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{|x|}{2\theta}\text{exp}\left(-\frac{|x|}{\theta}\right)\,\text{d}x = \theta\,.$$
Note: to compute the integral, alter its form by taking advantage of the fact that $|x|$ is symmetric (and, you can also decompose the integral based on cases for $|x|$).

Thus, the Fisher information is $$I(\theta)= \frac{2}{\theta^3}\mathbb{E}(\,|X|\,)-\frac{1}{\theta^2} = \frac{2}{\theta^2}-\frac{1}{\theta^2}=\frac{1}{\theta^2}$$
For a sample $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ of size $n$, the Fisher information is then 
$$I(\theta \,|\,n)=nI(\theta)=\frac{n}{\theta^2}\,.$$
Therefore, by the Cramér–Rao inequality, the variance of *any* unbiased estimator $\hat{\theta}$ of $\theta$ is bounded by the reciprocal of the Fisher information (this includes the MLE that you have computed, which achieves this lower bound, and is said to be an *efficient estimator*). In other words, $$\text{Var}(\hat{\theta}) \geq \frac{1}{nI(\theta)} = \frac{\theta^2}{n}\,\,.$$

Comment: but how do I differentiate $|x|$?

Comment: Simplify the integral using a symmetric argument, so that you won't have to...but for future reference, look up the signum function $\text{sgn}(x)$.

Comment: The substitution I mentioned is one way to compute the integral, but there are other ways...the symmetry of $|x|$ yields the best approach. @Brian

Comment: @Brian, in regards to making the integral manageable: what is $|x|$ for $x \geq 0$ and for $x < 0$? You can split the integral into these two cases and then apply the substitution and integration by parts.

Comment: thanks, I understand now. Looked up $sgn(x)$ and see why it works now!

Comment: No problem whatsoever! Happy to help! @Brian

Comment: @Brian note that I computed the information for a single sample of this distribution with parameter $\theta$, but you can generalize to a sample of size $n$ by inserting a sum $\sum_{i=1}^{n}$ before each $|X|$ and replacing each of these with $|X_i|$...however the calculation still reduces to finding the expectation of the $|X_i|$, which is what I have outlined.

Comment: yes, thanks, my problem was for a sample size of n but did generalise it

Answer (score 1):

To find MLE of $\theta$ we take likelihood function as $$L(x,\theta) = \frac{1}{(2\theta)^n} \exp \left( \frac{-\sum |x_i|}{\theta} \right).$$  Next we take its $\log$ as $$l(x,\theta) = - n \log 2 \theta - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|}{\theta}.$$  Differentiate w.r.t $\theta$ and equate to zero.  $$\frac{\partial l (x,\theta)}{\partial \theta} = \frac{-n}{\theta} + \frac{\sum |x_i|}{\theta^2} = 0$$ yields $$-n \theta + \sum |x_i| = 0$$ hence MLE is $$\theta = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|}{n}.$$

The Fisher information is given as $$I(\theta) = -E \left[ \frac{\partial^2 l(\theta)}{\partial \theta^2} \right]$$ i.e., expected value of the second derivative of the log likelihood $l(\theta)$.
$$\frac{\partial^2 l(\theta)}{\partial \theta^2} = \frac{n}{\theta^2} - \frac{ 2 \sum_{i=1}^n | x_i|}{\theta^3}$$ Taking expectation we have $$I(\theta) = - E \left[ \frac{\partial^2 l(\theta)}{\partial \theta^2} \right] = - \left[ \frac{n}{\theta^2} - \frac{2n\theta}{\theta^3} \right] = \frac{n}{\theta^2}.$$

---

Original images: [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBadP.png), [two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtRfz.png).

Comment: No I am not claiming E(sigma[x])=n theta. I have just edited my answer to make my point clear and that is sigma x(i)=n theta.

Comment: @afedder I had not taken expectation of the first partial derivative of theta w.r.t. "x". I had equated it to zero.

Comment: @ afedder Do check my answer.

Comment: You are correct, but there is no justification of the equalities after "taking the expectation we have", and hence, it is unhelpful to the OP.

Comment: I have attempted to typeset your images.  Please check to ensure that no errors have been introduced.

Comment: @ArthurFischer, thanks for typesetting, no error have been introduced.